# Компромисс между скоростью поиска и стоимостью хранения данных для больших текстовых данных

Tags: оптимизация, поиск, amazon-web-services, полнотекстовый-поиск

У меня есть AWS EC2 инстанс, я пытаюсь найти компромисс между скоростью поиска в файлах и стоимостью хранения. Я управляю большими объемами текстовых данных (~350 ГБ в файлах .txt), которые хранятся на жестком диске Amazon st1 HDD. Этот вариант является бюджетным, но существенно плохо влияет на скорость поиска.

Для сравнения, я использовал ripgrep для поиска текста, и мне потребовалось около 18 часов, чтобы ripgrep прошелся по всем файлам на диске st1 - это чрезвычайно долго. Ожидается, что эти поисковые запросы будут инициироваться одним пользователем несколько раз в неделю.

Одно из решений, о котором я подумал, заключается в том, чтобы во время поисковых запросов, программно обновлять диск st1 до SSD накопителя gp3 с помощью AWS SDK для повышения производительности. Поиск ripgrep на обновленном SSD занимает около 20 минут, что значительно быстрее по сравнению с диском st1. После я могу понизить диск до уровня st1, когда поиск будет завершен. Стоимость такого обновления до SSD составит $0,38 за 6 часов, что не дорого, а сам процесс масштабирования накопителя занимает около 12 минут. Однако у этого плана есть проблема: AWS разрешает только одно изменение диска каждые 6 часов. Представьте себе сценарий, когда диск только что был понижен, и сразу после этого пользователь запрашивает новый поиск - тогда он будет вынужден ждать 6 часов, прежде чем диск будет улучшен до SSD чтобы начать ускоренный поиск.

Ранее я экспериментировал с созданием инвертированного индекса для повышения скорости поиска. Но, к сожалению, это оказалось весьма неэффективным для меня - при использования индекса, операции поиска подстроки были примерно в 100 раз медленнее по сравнению с использованием ripgrep.

Более того, я рассматривал возможность использования Amazon RDS с PostgreSQL для управления и поиска в моих данных, но у меня огромный объём данных - миллиарды записей. Такой подход был бы непомерно дорогим для моего бюджета.

Поэтому я оказался в затруднительном положении. Я ищу решение, которое оптимально сбалансирует стоимость и скорость поиска без дорогостоящих управляемых баз данных или неэффективных методов индексирования. Как вы думаете, является ли мое решение наилучшим из возможных? Буду очень признателен любым воображениям!

Comment: Сложно сказать. Не очень понятно как и что ищется. Если это про какие то специфичные значения, то можно подумать об индексе. Если это про одинаковые запросы - можно подумать про кеширование. Если данные - это логи какие нибудь, но я бы подумал про какие то движки поисковые - типа elasticsearch. Потому тут никак не сказать, лучшее у вас решение или не лучшее.

Comment: @tym32167 специфичные значения. В каждой строке коленного файла два значения, условная структура: значение_1:значение_2. Поиск должен иметь возможность искать по любому из значений. Я уже тестировал вариант с построением индекса и если искать подстроку в индексированной строке, то этот поиск слишком медленный.

Comment: А что за запросы приходят? Типа «найти все пары чисел где значение-1 = ХХХ» ?

Comment: @tym32167 вы не поняли, значения не числовые. К примеру, NbQ367fer:lOpt6fgc. Нужно иметь возможность найти пару значений по вхождению подстроки в одно из значений. К примеру поиск подстроки Q36 должен вернуть описанную выше строку из файла и другие пары значений, где есть совпадение. Такого рода поиск с использованием индексов очень медленный. Да, поиск по индексам шустрый, если искать индексированные значения с префикса, типа NbQ... но не в случае поиска подстроки

Comment: Длины строковых значений ограничены? Например, от 1 до 10 символов? Окно поиска как то тоже ограничено? Например, поиск только если подстрока от 3 и более длиной? Какой количество уникальных значений? Например, 1000 уникальных значений могут в идеале формировать 1000 * 1000 пар, как у вас с этим соотношением?

Comment: ну и вопрос в догонку, этот файл на 350 гиг часто меняется? Туда что то дописывается/удялется? Как часто?

Comment: Да, как всегда все упирается в деньги. Хотите в самом деле быстро -- размажьте свои 350 гиг по сотне компов и запрашивайте параллельно  (кстати, у Raspberry 4 гб ОЗУ default)

Comment: @tym32167 возможная максимальная длина строки где-то 500 символов, состоящая из двух значений. в обычном режиме суммарная длинна значений около 30-50 символов. Поиск ограничен и производится начиная только с 3 символов. Первое значение уникальное, без дубликатов, второе может повторятся.

Comment: @tym32167 я рассматриваю возможность использовать Amazon Athena, учитывая что поиск не будет частым.

Comment: Просто набрасывая варианты, при длине пары 50, длина одного значения примерно 25, а количество пар около 3 миллиардов, что по сути позволяет каждому значению дать идентификатор (число) и пары описывать как пары чисел - если количество значений сильно меньше, чем количество пар, то это и место сэкономит и по каждому значению substring можно будет только 1 раз считать (то есть в теории поиск быстрее)